# CodeIgniter 2.1 - No validation_errors() displayed when validation fails on checkbox array?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have an array of two checkboxes in a form, setup the way [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222790/codeigniter-2-0-validating-arrays) suggests. Validation *appears* to fail, correctly, when no checkbox is selected but it looks like form_validation doesn't even run against empty checkboxes? Relevant code:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('groupcheck[]', 'groupcheck', 'required');
```

With no checkboxes selected this produces no errors when submitted (bad), and "validates" to false (good). 
When a checkbox is checked no errors are produced (good) and the form validates true (good).

Changing the validation to something which will always fail:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('groupcheck[]', 'groupcheck', 'valid_email');
```

With no checkboxes selected this produces no errors when submitted (bad), and "validates" to false (good). 
When a checkbox is checked a valid email error is produced (good) and the form validates false (good).

So is this an issue with the browser not returning any data to form_validation when no checkboxes are selected? How would you go about displaying errors when a checkbox isn't selected?

Comment: can you please post your controller + view code so we can check?

Comment: posting some relevant code would help us know what is going on. but in the meantime, u might want to try showing individual errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I added a form_hidden() field to my view, then the form_validation will always run even with no checkboxes checked